# Creating object for Map interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, interface

Here by using "new" keyword I am creating object for Map interface (in Java we cannot create objects for interface, generally).
I do not understand, without implementing Map interface which is TypeScript based, how the code works?

```js
let map1= new Map()
map1.set(12,"User1");
map1.forEach((k,v) => console.log(k,v))
```

In Java I am implementing the interface Map using HashMap class, I am able to create object of HashMap class. In Java, I am not allowed to create Map object using "new" keyword:

```java
public class User{
    public void createMap(){
        Map<Integer,String> map1= new HashMap();
        map1.put(12,"NameOne");
    }
}
```

Comment: Map isn't _"TypeScript based"_ (it's part of JavaScript) and isn't just an interface (JavaScript doesn't _have_ interfaces, that's something TypeScript adds): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Map interface is shown in - lib.es2015.colletion.d.ts. Can you elaborate?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/5c3045bc4f0d7b9a3e0d43cbf091ced99db8953c/src/lib/es2015.collection.d.ts#L1-L35 contains the **type definition** of the underlying JavaScript class, so that the compiler knows what methods etc. those objects have.

Comment: I realized that I did not go anywhere by asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS `Map` is a *class*, not just an *interface*

[image]

If it would be interface, you'd get this error
[image]